# Return DB results within Date Range

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, date-range

In my view, I have an input and select tags for the user to enter a start and end date.
When submitted, The controller will search the Model/Database and return entries within the above range.

In my DB, the start and end dates are written as "nvarchars" and in my controller they are taken as strings

Code and Images for reference:

```
public ActionResult timePeriod(string time)
{
    //Start: month, day, year End: month, day, year --> Numeric values
    string[] times = time.Split(',');                             
    string start = times[0] + " " + times[1] + " " + times[2];
    string end = times[3] + " " + times[4] + " " + times[5];

    //Sample code to test the start date
    viewModel.Tasks = db.Tasks.Where(s => s.StartTime.Contains(start)).ToList();
}
```

a snippet of the Database values:

[image]

Are there any LINQ expression to do this?

Comment: Why aren't the dates stored as `datetime`? Seems unusual to store them as `nvarchar`

Comment: unfortunately, I am unable to chnage the database, thus have to deal with the dates being varchars

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the dates are strings, you've nothing better other than using what you have suggested already:

```
viewModel.Tasks = db.Tasks.Where(s => s.StartTime.Equals(start)).ToList();
```

I would use `Equals` as that will be quicker for you. Using Contains is basically like doing a T-SQL `LIKE` which is much slower.

```
SELECT *
FROM Table
WHERE StartDate LIKE 'blah'
```

Using `Equals` will result in the following equivalent:

```
SELECT *
FROM Table
WHERE StartDate = 'blah'
```

Which is much more efficient.

Comment: alright thanks for the reply,perhaps i need to talk to the DB admins to change the type of the dates.

Comment: I would suggest doing that, as it makes sense for those dates to be `datetime` values. However, if the database has already been created, and is being used, then changing the type may be too late now.

Comment: well the project is still in development, so its worth asking, cause I can imagine the logic is gonna be complex to get all the DB entries between the dates.

Comment: You've hit the nail in the head there. With `nvarchar` you could not easily get a date range between two dates.